# callkit reload extension in ios

Tags: ios, swift4, ios-app-extension, callkit

i am creating app like as trucaller. Everything is completed, only one issue remaining. issue is that how to reload application extension after add new contact number from server in app. first of all, i enter some static number in the array then after i store it in userdefault. i got this by app-groups functionality. i want that when user synchronize their contact in my application, i want reload contact list.

this is my code

```
manager.reloadExtension(withIdentifier: extensionIdentifer, completionHandler: { error in
                print("error \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                if let _ = error{
                    print("A error \(error?.localizedDescription as String!)");
                }
            })
```

this is give me error like below

> "sqlite3_step for query 'INSERT INTO PhoneNumberBlockingEntry
> (extension_id, phone_number_id) VALUES (?, (SELECT id FROM PhoneNumber
> WHERE (number = ?)))' returned 19 (2067) errorMessage 'UNIQUE
> constraint failed: PhoneNumberBlockingEntry.extension_id,
> PhoneNumberBlockingEntry.phone_number_id'"

Comment: It looks like you have loaded invalid data to your extension; the phone_number_id is not unique; check your data

Answer (score 1):

Jaydeep: Call your new contact web service or synchronize contacts in application and just reload extension as -

```
 CXCallDirectoryManager.sharedInstance.getEnabledStatusForExtension(withIdentifier: "com.compname.sampleapp", completionHandler: { (enabledStatus,error) ->

                        Void in if let error = error {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)

                        }
                        CXCallDirectoryManager.sharedInstance.reloadExtension(withIdentifier:"com.compname.sampleapp", completionHandler: {
                            (error) ->

                            Void in if let error = error {
                                print(error.localizedDescription)


                            }

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.hud?.hide(animated: true)
                            }
                        })

                        print("No error")
                    })
```

Let me know still issue getting. I have done this and working fine.